# Non-virtual version of vtkDataArrayTemplate

Tags: abstract-class, vtk

I have a template class `myClass<T>`, where T can be a *scalar* (float, int, double, etc.)
I would like to create a `vtkFloatArray`, `vtkIntArray`, or `vtkDoubleArray`, depending on the type T.

I thought that `vtkDataArrayTemplate<T>` would be a good solution.
Unfortunately, it is a virtual class, so I can't write this :

```
vtkSmartPointer< vtkDataArrayTemplate<T> > array =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArrayTemplate<T> >::New();
```

because when I try to instantiate a myClass, I get the error :

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘vtkObject*’ to ‘vtkDataArrayTemplate<float>*’ [-fpermissive]`
```

I think it's because `vtkDataArrayTemplate::New()` doesn't exist (because the class is virtual), so `vtkObject::New()` is called instead. Then we understand that it can't transform a `vtkObject` into a `vtkDataArrayTemplate`.

So my question is:

Is there an non-virtual version of `vtkDataArrayTemplate` that would allow me to create a `vtkFloatArray` when T is `float`, `vtkDoubleArray` when T is `double`, etc. ?

P.S: I use VTK 6.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An email to the vtk-users mailing list helped me on this too.
A useful static function in [vtkDataArray](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataArray.html#aebe8b3680c8c9760211c34ae5f292b04)  has been pointed to me:

```
vtkDataArray::CreateDataArray(int dataType)
```

It allows to create a data array of the type dataType.

Now, to transform the template parameter `T` into a vtk type, I used the code I mentionned in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476714/compare-vtk-data-types-and-basic-data-types/36721731#36721731): (thank you **norisknofun**)

```
#include <vtkType.h>

int GetVTKType(std::size_t hash_code)
{
    static std::map<std::size_t, long> typeMap;
    if(typeMap.empty())
    {
        typeMap[typeid(void).hash_code()]               = VTK_VOID;
        typeMap[typeid(char).hash_code()]               = VTK_CHAR;
        typeMap[typeid(signed char).hash_code()]        = VTK_SIGNED_CHAR;
        typeMap[typeid(unsigned char).hash_code()]      = VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR;
        typeMap[typeid(short).hash_code()]              = VTK_SHORT;
        typeMap[typeid(unsigned short).hash_code()]     = VTK_UNSIGNED_SHORT;
        typeMap[typeid(int).hash_code()]                = VTK_INT;
        typeMap[typeid(unsigned int).hash_code()]       = VTK_UNSIGNED_INT;
        typeMap[typeid(long).hash_code()]               = VTK_LONG;
        typeMap[typeid(unsigned long).hash_code()]      = VTK_UNSIGNED_LONG;
        typeMap[typeid(float).hash_code()]              = VTK_FLOAT;
        typeMap[typeid(double).hash_code()]             = VTK_DOUBLE;
        typeMap[typeid(std::string).hash_code()]        = VTK_STRING;
        typeMap[typeid(long long).hash_code()]          = VTK_LONG_LONG;
        typeMap[typeid(unsigned long long).hash_code()] = VTK_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG;
        typeMap[typeid(int64_t).hash_code()]            = VTK___INT64;
        typeMap[typeid(uint64_t).hash_code()]           = VTK_UNSIGNED___INT64;
    }
    return typeMap[hash_code];
}
```

So the final code is:

```
vtkDataArray *array = 
    vtkDataArray::CreateDataArray(GetVTKType(typeid(T).hash_code()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the same logic of the other vtk [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476714/compare-vtk-data-types-and-basic-data-types/36479505#36479505), you can make a factory with the a map of type

```
std::map< vtktypes , std::function< void*() > > _map;
```

`std::function< void*() >` aims to be a simple object creator, returning `void*` which then needs to be statically casted into the target type.

like :

```
_map[VTK_INT] = [](){ return new vtkFloatArray(); }
```

Comment: vtk-users told me this map between vtk type and call to the right function exists, and it's in `vtkDataArray::CreateDataArray(int dataType)`.